# Don't stop believing

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Sleeps through the day, awake in the night,
> To brighten and shine, is their delight.
>
> A few may seem, like they're missing their sheen,
> Right in the city, it's where they have been.
>
> Go through the day, mostly unnoticed,
> Right in your face, I'll give you focus.
>
> Over the streets, you will see my feats,
> Under the sky, you will see me lie.
>
> Not fat and round, I'm bound on the ground,
> Dawn upon us, I wait for the bus.

What am I?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you might be a

> Street light

Sleeps through the day, awake in the night,

> Street lights are usually set to come on when dark

To brighten and shine, is their delight.

> They light up the darkness.

A few may seem, like their missing their sheen,

> Street lights are normally not cleaned very often and can lose their sheen quickly.

Right in the city, it's where they have been.

> Mostly are located in cities.

Go through the day, mostly unnoticed,

> Street lights are not switched on during the day.

Right in your face, I'll give you focus.

> Not sure about this one, but possibly, if you are about to bump into one, you will be more focused.

Over the streets, you will see my feats,

> The lights themselves are above the streets

Under the sky, you will see me lie.

> Street lights essentially act as artificial daylight.

Not fat and round, I'm bound on the ground,

> Street lights are connected to the ground, usually not fat and round.

Dawn upon us, I wait for the bus.

> Street lights are often positioned near bus stops.

Hidden clue

> The first letter of each line spells STARGROUND which could be a hint for a street light.

Title: Don't Stop Believing

> Part of the lyrics of the song are 
>  *Strangers waiting 
>  Up and down the boulevard 
>  Their shadows searching in the night 
>  **Streetlights**, people 
>  Living just to find emotion 
>  Hiding somewhere in the night*

Comment: Wow, this was fast. Good job.